# How do I test if the average difference between two groups are statistically significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey, mean

Suppose I conduct a survey of 1000 males and 1000 females about their age and I found that the average male age is 50 while the average female age is 40. What information do I need and how do I test if the average age of males is significantly different from the average age of females?

Comment: you can also use the non parametric tests. well since you have a large sample you can always say that your variables are normal, but just in case.

Comment: @haifa Unfortunately, nothing like this is true: the larger the sample becomes, the more evident it will be that it is from a *non* Normal population.  You appear to confuse statements about sampling *statistics* (as in the Central Limit Theorem) with statements about the sample *distribution.*

Comment: Is this a question for some subject, or from a textbook or similar?

Answer (score 0):

The t-test of student can be used to compare average values between two groups.

Before using a t-test, there are two conditions that should be verified for validity of this test.

1. In each group, there should be atleast 20 to 30 observations.
2. The variable being studied should approximately follow a normal distribution.

Comment: a. What is the basis for your requirement in "1."? ... b. having two means, 30 observations and normal distributions is not enough information to perform a t-test.

Comment: What information is needed to perform a t-test? As little information as possible

Comment: @Glen_b : i guess the first requirement is necessary in order to have enough observations (around 20-30) allowing to check the normality of a variable (to draw the distribution curve for example). But i agree that this condition is not sufficient.

Comment: If you're prepared to assume approximate normality (which might be reasonable if you know something about the likely age distribution), you don't need to check normality -- but in any case, with a variable like age and n=1000, you don't need it; the mean ages will be essentially normally distributed and the error on the estimate of $\sigma$ could probably be ignored (giving a z-test) ...